# YA fantasy novel about princesses, one must quest to save the other

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

This is a pretty short YA novel I read circa 2010, although I don't think it was a new book at that time.  I think the author was female and may have authored several additional books about princesses.

The story is about two princesses who were sisters. One was shy and the other was outgoing. I'm not sure if these are accurate memories, but I think the shy one had dark straight hair and the outgoing one had curly red hair. One sister gets abducted by a dragon and the other has to make a journey to rescue her from its lair. When she reaches the lair, she is forced to stay there for a few days (I don't remember why). She eventually kills the dragon with a sword and takes her sister home. The book contains the quote "Set your face toward danger, and your heart on victory".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [*The Two Princesses of Bamarre*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/183656.The_Two_Princesses_of_Bamarre) (2004) by Gail Carson Levine.

[image: Cover of "The Two Princesses of Bamarre"]

The publisher details in this [Google books entry](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/The_Two_Princesses_of_Bamarre/3fPWwAEACAAJ?hl=en) say:

> "Step follows step.
> Hope follows courage.
> **Set your face toward danger.
>
> Set your heart on victory.**"
>
> Princess Meryl dreams of one day protecting the kingdom of Bamarre, while timid Princess Addie is content to stay always within the safety of the castle walls. The one trait they share is their devotion to each other. Their world is turned upside down, though, when Meryl is stricken by the incurable Gray Death. To save her sister, Addie must set out on a **dangerous quest filled with dragons**, unknown magic, and death itself. Time is running out, and the sisters’ lives -- and the future of Bamarre -- hang in the balance.

So it may not be exactly what you remember (Meryl is sick, not kidnapped) but there are 2 sisters of different appearance and the quieter one must go on a quest involving dragons.

Comment: Yes, this is it!!!!! Thank you so much!! :) How did you find it? Maybe I will try the same method to locate the first book.

Comment: In fact, I have found the first book, "Fairest" by the same author, simply by googling the author's other books. Thanks again!!

Comment: Fairest is a (loose) sequel to GCL's most famous book, Ella Enchanted, if you're interested. :)